# Chromium/WebKit render to OpenGL texture

Tags: c++, opengl, webkit, browser, chromium

Last few days I have been looking around the chromium and WebKit source codes, reading wikis, and watching Google videos. What I want to do is take what WebKit renders and place it into a GL texture. But I need to have different DOM nodes in different textures. I have a few questions and Im not sure if I should go about using Chromium or implementing my own simple browser. Chromium obviously has many nice features, but it is *very* large and extensive. I also figure that it's algorithms for splitting render layers are unpredictable (I want pretty much full control).

1. Where should in WebKit or Chromium's source to find where it outputs raster data? It would be convenient if I could get access to Chromium's render layer raster data before it is composted. But as I said the render layers would probably me mixed in a way I didn't want them to be.
2. Is WebKit GPU accelerated, in that case I should be able to access the data directly. I know Chromium+Blink is but I can't find out if WebKit on its own is.
3. How much work is it too put together a simple browser?

P.S. I can't use Awesomium because I need to render different DOM nodes/subtrees into different textures. Chromium Embedded Framework doesn't appear to have support for DOM manipulation either and I believe it just renders the entire page and gives you the raster data.

Comment: In CEF you can exchange messages between Javascript and C++. The correct way designed by the browser itself is to manipulate DOM by Javascript.